# Do spring-data-jpa annotations not work in webflux environment?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I am new to spring webflux and want to build my first application.

I am used to build my entities first and give them anntotations like **javax.persitence.Entity, javax.persitence.OneToMany**, ... and let spring generate my tables for me.

But...in all tutorials I found there is always only the **@Table** annotation used and there is no spring-boot-starter-jpa dependencies in the pom. Webflux does not even seem to work anymore if I add that dependency (Then there were no ReacticeCrudRepositories found anymore). All tables were created manually.

So using spring-boot-starter-jpa and its annotations seems to be forbidden.

**But how do I model my entities, e.g. OneToMany and ManyToOne when I do not have my annotations anymore?**

**Is there no auto-generate option anymore?**

Thank you very much

Comment: JPA is blocking, there is no reactive JPA so that won't work together (well it can but it wouldn't be fully reactive anymore). What you see in the tutorials is the usage of Spring Data R2DBC (or plain Spring R2DBC) which is a reactive database implementation.

Comment: Thx, but my question is still open. But how do I model my entities, e.g. OneToMany and ManyToOne when I do not have thy JPA annotations anymore?

Comment: You cannot use JPA so you need something else, like R2DBC. No there are no annotations for that and you need to do mapping yourself.

Comment: Ok, thats a hint....by myself. So in case of a one-to-many, I have to save the one and then iterate over the many and save them with the set id of the one? So I would build a extra layer on top of the R2DBC-Repos and under my Service-layer, that does this job?